# Extract text from element within an input class

Tags: c#, selenium

So I am currently test automating in Visual Studio with C# and Selenium. So my problem is as follows. The element I want to extract text from is:

```
<input class="showroomprice pricehistory" type="text" data-showroomprice="100000" value="100.000" data-tooltip="true" data-html="true" data-original-title="<div class=&quot;price-history-popup&quot;>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                Datum
            </th>
            <th>
                Showroom
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tr>
        <td>
            22 feb 2017
        </td>
        <td>
            € 100.000
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            27 jul 2016
        </td>
        <td>
            € 399.999
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            20 jan 2016
        </td>
        <td>
            € 333.333
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            20 jan 2016
        </td>
        <td>
            € 123
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            20 jan 2016
        </td>
        <td>
            € 12.333
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>">
```

Now as you can see, the div and table are part of the input class (See the "> after the div in last line). When I find element by class showroomprice pricehistory and try to get text, I get a null value back. I cannot locate element by div class either.

So what I need is, I need to create a string with ALL the text that is noted within the table. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the element you want to extract text from? `input` or `table`?

Comment: Does the rendered HTML actually appear as above with the div + table as a string in the input `original-data-title` attribute?

Answer (score 0):

write a loop to concatenate the text from all cells, sample java code

```
import java.util.List;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;

public class WebTableExample 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
        driver.get("test url");      
        string tableText;
        WebElement table_element = driver.findElement(By.id("yourtable id"));
        List<WebElement> tr_collection=table_element.findElements(By.xpath("id('testTable')/tbody/tr"));

        int row_num,col_num;
        row_num=1;
        for(WebElement trElement : tr_collection)
        {
            List<WebElement> td_collection=trElement.findElements(By.xpath("td"));

            col_num=1;
            for(WebElement tdElement : td_collection)
            {
             // making all cells text to tableText
                tableText = tableText + tdElement.getText();

                col_num++;
            }
            row_num++;
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think this will work as the table is actually part of a string as part of the `data-original-title` attribute of the `input`

Comment: In that case it is more simple, extract attribute value and replace all TD, TR tags with blank